# How to run a line only once when using mpi4py

Tags: python, mpi4py

Say I have a simple program, `foo.py`:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

# Some stuff happens here

print "Done"
```

and run it using `mpiexec -n 4 python foo.py`, it prints "Done" 4 times.

How do I get it to print "Done" only once, at the end?

I tried

```
if rank == 3:
    print "Done"
```

but this is not guaranteed to be last. The documentation regarding I/O for mpi4py is not complete.

Comment: You can use a `MPI.COMM_WORLD.Barrier()` to make sure that all processes have reached that point in the code.

Comment: Oh, so if I put that before `if rank == 3` (or even `if rank == 0` then) it would print "Done" last?

Comment: Yes, and you can also flush the output of Python print for all processes, before the barrier, just to make sure. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print